# How to select one row per user conditionally?

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I have the following query:

```
select count(1) num, business_id, user_id FROM `pos_transactions` 
group by user_id, business_id
order by user_id
```

It returns this:

```
+--------+-------------+---------+
|  num   | business_id | user_id |
+--------+-------------+---------+
| 3      | 503         | 12      |
| 7      | 33          | 12      |
| 1      | 771         | 13      |
| 2      | 86          | 13      |
| 1      | 772         | 13      |
| 4      | 652         | 14      |
| 4      | 567         | 14      |
+--------+-------------+---------+
```

I need to select only one row per `user_id`, the one which has a bigger `num` value. If all `num` values for a user are identical, then just one of them should be selected randomly (i.e. user `#14`). So, here is the expected result:

```
+--------+-------------+---------+
|  num   | business_id | user_id |
+--------+-------------+---------+
| 7      | 33          | 12      |
| 2      | 86          | 13      |
| 4      | 567         | 14      |
+--------+-------------+---------+
```

Any idea how can I do that?

---

I guess the solution will be something related to `limit 1` per user. But I have no idea how I should write the query.

**All I want to do is making the table unique per `user_id`, and the logic is selecting rows that have bigger `num`.**

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Really? My question is not clear enough?

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas `Server version: 8.0.20 - MySQL Community Server - GPL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MAX()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) num, 
       FIRST_VALUE(business_id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) business_id, 
       user_id 
FROM pos_transactions 
GROUP BY user_id, business_id
ORDER BY user_id
```

Comment: That's great .. thanks for your answer .. just out of curiosity, I will be appreciated if you also share the old mysql version solution ..

Comment: @stack I would not even attempt a solution without window functions. It would involve subqueries and the use of inline variables which are deprecated in MySql 8.0+.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway .. you know, the problem is your query looks really heavy and is not executable for the huge dataset I have in reality. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAnBd.png

Comment: @stack I tried to describe in my previous comment what type of solution you would get without window functions. A solution that uses window functions for your requirement certainly performs better than any other without them. For large datasets the performance can be improved by adding indexes. I assume that user_id is indexed. Also an index on user_id, business_id combined may help.

Comment: Yeah, your mentioned indexes already exist .. I will try to get a dump of the table and import it into a stronger server (hardware) and retry to run the query. Just for my information, there is the `PARTITION` keyword used in your query twice .. is it a thing related to partitioning? Since I didn't use MySQL partitioning on that table.

Comment: @stack no, PARTITION is part of the syntax used inside OVER() for window functions. For example PARTITION BY user_id means that the rows are grouped by user_id.

Comment: What does DISTINCT do?

Comment: @Strawberry in the GROUP BY clause there are both user_id and business_id. The query must return 1 row for each user_id. This is what DISTINCT does.